# Find the sampling rate of my network interface card in which /proc/net/wireless is updated

Tags: networking, network-manager

I need to extract the sampling rate of the network interface card in which the statistics and data in `/proc/net/wireless` such as signal strength are updated.

I am writing a script that reads the RSSI value stream and study its change. I need to collect 300 sample in minimum time. If I specify the time between each consecutive two samples readings to be smaller that the sampling rate of the network card it will report the same RSSI twice as a cached value.